# Align image in div & give div space from card

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make a little "card", to show information about products. Now I want a little picture of each product at the top, but I need to center it verticle and horizontally.

I also need to give the image/div a little space, tried doing margin-top: 1em; but didn't do anything at all.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for auction in auctions%}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="auction-item">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img
            src="/static/img/grass.png"
            alt="Grass Block"
            class="item-icon"
          />
        </div>
        <h2>{{ auction.name }}</h2>
        <div class="average-price">
          <h3>Average Price: {{ auction.start_bid }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="time-left">
          <h3>Time Left: time</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="graph-div">
          <a class="graph-tag" href="#">Show Graph</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS can be found here:

```
.img-container {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-icon {
  width: 80%;
}

.auction-item {
  width: 275px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 3em;
}

.auction-item h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.auction-item h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.graph-div {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.graph-tag {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

And here is how it looks right now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (position: relative) in your container css

```
.img-container {
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #333;
margin-top: 1em;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
```

}

and your image class add

```
.item-icon {
width: 80%;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When you want some content to be placed exactly at the center then always remember to use `positions`(relative & absolute) this will help the data to sit within the element.

> 1. Use `flex` and use `vertical-align`(optional) to center.
> 2. Use `top:5%;` to bring the image tag down on `.img-container{...}`

```css
.auction-item {
  width: 275px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 3em;
}

.img-container {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
}

.item-icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.auction-item h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.auction-item h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.graph-div {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.graph-tag {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for auction in auctions%}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="auction-item">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="Grass Block" class="item-icon" />
        </div>
        <h2>{{ auction.name }}</h2>
        <div class="average-price">
          <h3>Average Price: {{ auction.start_bid }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="time-left">
          <h3>Time Left: time</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="graph-div">
          <a class="graph-tag" href="#">Show Graph</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```